# "www" issue on WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, dns, digital-ocean

I just starting with WordPress, I am using Digital Ocean and a domain. I went to WordPress setting and added "www" to website name as it was naked before, the site stopped working and shows nothing now. How to fix this?

Comment: Are you getting just a blank browser screen? If so, do you have any errors in your PHP/Apache logs? You may find [these domain override instructions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) useful.

Answer (score 1):

After changing the site URL and home URL to www, you need to add ServerName as www.yourdomainname.com

Assuming you have a single host.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Change the file as below.

```
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
ServerAlias yourdomain.com
```

Now you need to have 2 A records with hostnames @ and www pointing to your IP in your DNS.

Hope this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Who did you buy your domain through? You should go to your settings there and change your DNS settings to do a www redirect for you. Then just make sure the box is listening for the site name with the www prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Usually changing the domain name for a site isn't quite this simple, although adding in 'www' shouldn't cause too much grief I'd think.

However, to get things back up and running, you'll want to get into your site's database (via PHPMyAdmin or something like that) and open the wp_options table. In the first page of that table, you should see an entry for site_url, which you can edit and remove the 'www'. That should at least get you back up and running. Then we can sort out what the other issue is with the subdomain.